# Use DTO to map JSON to final object, or just parse JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing, dto, pojo

I have some json object that looks like this:

```
{
   "make":"Volvo",
   "model":"240",
   "metadata":{
      "color":"white",
      "year":"1986",
      "previousOwner":"Joe",
      "condition":"good"
   }
}
```

And I want to turn this JSON into `List<Car>`, which is comprised of the following objects:

```
public class Car {

    private String make;

    private String model;

    private CarMetadata carMetadata;

}

public class CarMetadata {

    private Body body;

    private History history;

}

public class Body {

    private String color;

    private String condition;

}

public class History {

    private String previousOwner;

    private String year;

}
```

So essentially the point is that the object I want to turn it into (Car) is very nested, whereas my JSON is not very nested. In reality the "Car" object is actually much more nested than this example I'm showing.

I was thinking of two options:

1. Create a CarDTO object to represent my input JSON, do `objectMapper.readValue(json, CarDTO.class)`, then map CarDTO to Car to create my `List<Car>`.
2. Just parse the JSON and create the final `List<Car>` object in the first place.

I don't want to create an unnecessary DTO, but I also don't want to mess with parsing this JSON.

Is there a best practice in this scenario, and would this even be a valid use of a DTO?

Comment: Are you persisting Car to a database using a library like hibernate or JPA?

Comment: You have a structural mismatch between your JSON and your object model.  You will need to write code to bridge the gap.  Where that code lives will depend on how you intend to use the various objects and contained objects, and without much more detail there won't be a "right" answer.

Comment: @Bohemian No I'm not, I'm passing List<Car> to some downstream logic

Comment: @JimGarrison This is a pretty separated process from the rest of the code that will use the object model. That is why I was having trouble deciding which to use, because all this job is doing is getting the JSON from S3, turning it into the correct object, and passing it to something downstream.

Comment: Best practice will be to write the adapter code to convert in both directions ONCE and encapsulate it all in one place so if you ever need to change it, you only have to change one source module.  It would also help to specify the adapter as an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DTO.

Although you *can* deserialize from json directly to your domain class, their structure differs so you would have to create a custom deserializer... DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME. I've been there and it's completely not worth the hassle.

Use the DTO to parse the json into a POJO, then map the DTO to the domain object.

This will decouple the transport from your domain object, allowing both to change freely with only the mapping code being affected. It's also way easier to write, understand, test and debug.